# expected spyOn function to be called Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, testing, jestjs

im currently trying to test the methods that i have created and the methods in my if statement are not being called. and im completely at a loss. I am new too jest though so im sure its something simple im missing.

```html
 describe('isSingleScreen', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      jest.clearAllMocks();
      jest.spyOn(utilMethods, 'isDualScreen').mockReturnValue(true);
    });

    it('autoScreenAdd', () => {
      // Arrange
      const singleScreenAddSpy = jest.spyOn(
        singleScreenMethods,
        'singleScreenAdd'
      );
      const dualScreenAddSpy = jest.spyOn(dualScreenMethods, 'dualScreenAdd');

      // Act
      utilMethods.autoScreenAdd({});

      // Assert
      expect(singleScreenAddSpy).toBeCalledTimes(0);
      expect(dualScreenAddSpy).toBeCalled();
      expect(dualScreenAddSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
```

```html
export const isDualScreen = (): boolean => {
  return Dimensions.get('window').width > 1000 ? true : false;
};

export const autoScreenAdd = (element: IDualComponent) => {
  if (isDualScreen()) {
    dualScreenAdd(element);
  } else {
    singleScreenAdd(element);
  }
};
```

this is the error i receive

```html
    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 0
    Received number of calls: 1

      30 |       // Assert
      31 |       expect(autoScreenAddSpy).toBeCalled();
    > 32 |       expect(singleScreenAddSpy).toBeCalledTimes(0);
         |                                  ^
      33 |       expect(dualScreenAddSpy).toBeCalled();
      34 |       expect(dualScreenAddSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      35 |     });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a limitation to how you can test a module that contains functions which call other functions within the same module. [See this article for some more insight](https://medium.com/@DavideRama/mock-spy-exported-functions-within-a-single-module-in-jest-cdf2b61af642). There are few ways to work around this in that article, so I recommend taking a look at that first before diving into my rough implementation as it may not work with your code structure 100%.

## Working Example:

[CodesandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-shape-e2mjc?file=/src/utils.js)

### Utils

Slightly modified from your original, so you may need to mimic this in your util modules as necessary.

```
const isDualScreen = () => {
  return window.width > 1000 ? true : false;
};

const autoScreenAdd = element => {
  if (utilMethods.isDualScreen()) {
    utilMethods.dualScreenAdd(element);
  } else {
    utilMethods.singleScreenAdd(element);
  }
};

const dualScreenAdd = element => {
  return element;
};

const singleScreenAdd = element => {
  return element;
};

// This is important, it allows you to mock the functions properly in your tests.
// Use this same structure in your singleScreenMethods and dualScreenMethods modules
const utilMethods = {
  singleScreenAdd,
  dualScreenAdd,
  autoScreenAdd,
  isDualScreen
};

export default utilMethods;
```

### Test Example

```
import utilMethods from "./utils";

describe("isSingleScreen", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    jest.spyOn(utilMethods, "isDualScreen").mockReturnValue(true);
  });

  it("autoScreenAdd", () => {
    // Arrange
    const singleScreenAddSpy = jest.spyOn(utilMethods, "singleScreenAdd");
    const dualScreenAddSpy = jest.spyOn(utilMethods, "dualScreenAdd");

    // Act
    utilMethods.autoScreenAdd({});

    // Assert
    expect(singleScreenAddSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
    expect(dualScreenAddSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: I have but unfortunately it returns the same result. ill keep it in mind though as a best practice :)

Comment: [This might help you](https://medium.com/@DavideRama/mock-spy-exported-functions-within-a-single-module-in-jest-cdf2b61af642)

Comment: @keil Updated my answer with those findings and a working example on codesandbox, hope it helps!

Comment: Think it was ["jest spyon util functions"](https://www.google.com/search?ei=OpKOXrDxL-6LytMP3tKBkAM&q=jest+spyon+util+functions&oq=jest+spyon+util+functions&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAM6BAgeEAo6BggAEAcQHjoFCAAQzQJQ_a4BWMzSAWDY1QFoAnAAeACAAV2IAZUFkgECMTKYAQCgAQE&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp#sbfbu=1&pi=jest%20spyon%20util%20functions)