# Jest spyOn doesn't recognize function call

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have a node module with two functions:

`authenticate()`
and
`signIn()`

`authenticate` calls `signIn` as a helper function
both are exported from the module like so:

```
module.exports = { authenticate, signIn };
```

I'm following the advice given for a similar issue found here:
[expected spyOn function to be called Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61111423/expected-spyon-function-to-be-called-jest)

Logging out the contents of the module in my test results in confirmation that both methods are present:

```
      {
        authenticate: [AsyncFunction: authenticate],
        signIn: [AsyncFunction: signIn]
      }
```

I spy on `signIn` when `authentication` is under test to ensure it was called, and I know it was called because a message from `signIn` logs out to the console.
I would expect this test to pass, however it fails saying there were 0 calls when >=1 were expected.

```
const auth = require("./authenticate");

test("should signIn", async () => {
  console.log(auth);
  const signInSpy = jest.spyOn(auth, "signIn").mockResolvedValue({ access_token: "123" });
  await auth.authenticate();
  expect(signInSpy).toBeCalled();
});
```

I assume I have set something up incorrectly since calling `auth.authenticate()` does actually call the `auth` module's `signIn`, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Could you show the code for the authenticate module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code for `authenticate.js` looks like this, where authenticate calls `signIn` directly, Jest will not mock that value as it is a reference to the original function, not a property on the exported object.

```js
// Doesn't work
const signIn = () => console.log("Signed in");
// `signIn` will never be anything other than the function above
const authenticate = () => signIn();

module.exports = {
  authenticate,
  signIn
};
```

If you used the `module.exports` object, either directly or by using `this`, you would be able to access the spied version from Jest in your test.

```js
// Works
module.exports.signIn = () => console.log("Signed in");
module.exports.authenticate = () => module.exports.signIn();
```

```js
// Also works
module.exports = {
  authenticate: function () {
    this.signIn();
  },
  signIn: () => console.log("Signed in")
};
```

If these solutions don't work well for your original code, you may want to partially mock the authenticate.js module, or separate your functions into different files.

Comment: wound up separating the functions into different files - thank you @evelynhathaway